# Email template under wwwroot is not found

Tags: .net, azure-devops

I have some email templates under the `wwwroot` folder which I use on my EmailService. It works on local but when I launch the web app into the Azure VSTS I get the error

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Root directory /app/wwwwroot/Templates not found
>   at RazorLight.Razor.FileSystemRazorProject..ctor(String root)

[image: folder structure]

csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Contratos" Version="1.0.0-CI-20191001-130431" />
        <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="2.3.1.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="MassTransit" Version="5.5.6-develop.2181" />
        <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Autofac" Version="5.5.6-develop.2181" />
        <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core" Version="5.5.6-develop.2181" />
        <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.5.6-develop.2181" />
        <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.5.6-develop.2181" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" Version="3.0.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="RazorLight" Version="2.0.0-beta1" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\StaticFiles\images\common\background.png" />
      <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\StaticFiles\images\common\bottom-bord
      <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\StaticFiles\images\common\youtube-logo_3x.png" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="wwwroot\StaticFiles" />
      <Folder Include="wwwroot\Templates" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Contratos\Contratos.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Update: if add this to csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="wwwroot\Templates\Password" />
      <Folder Include="wwwroot\StaticFiles\images" />
</ItemGroup>
```

the error changes to

> Project can not find template with key BlockedLogin.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

In VisualStudio, Goto Templates folder. Select the files that you want to have under wwwroot\templates folder. And select file properties and modify the settings to

1. Build Action: **Content**
2. Copy To Output Directory: **Always**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MVC precompiles `cshtml` in wwwroot folder, generating `views.dlls`.

To disable it is necessary to explicit:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can use the files as template.